# Help with substr()

Tags: php, string, substr

I want to remove everything before #blitz in this string:

```
$twit = rt @danisan01: #blitz ipva em frente ao barra sul, no recreio.
```

here's what I'm trying but I get no results on the output:

```
$array_bols = array("#bols", "#blitz", "#blitz ipva", "#ipva", "#detran", "#blitz de ipva", "#detran ipva", "#blitz d ipva");

foreach($array_bols as $blitz)
{
$twit = substr(strstr($twit, $blitz), strlen($blitz), (-1) * strlen($twit));
}
```

help

Comment: What is your objective here? What's the value of $twit after 1 iteration? After the loop is complete?

Comment: Also, `#bols` is not present in your string.

Comment: Sorry, edited it $twit is the string, I want it to output:

 #blitz ipva em frente ao barra sul, no recreio.

and by #bols I mean anything that is in the array $array_bols

Comment: ok first $twit should be `$twit .=` this way you are not overwriting after each loop

Answer (score 0):

You get no output, because you iterate over a list of search words. And your $twit variable will be emptied at some point, because `strstr` returns nothing if it can't find the searched subject.

What you wanted to do is following:

```
$array_bols = array("#bols", "#blitz", "#blitz ipva", "#ipva", "#detran", "#blitz de ipva", "#detran ipva", "#blitz d ipva");

foreach($array_bols as $blitz)
{
    if ($tmp = strstr($twit, $blitz)) {
        $twit = substr($tmp, strlen($blitz));
    }
}
```

The inner substr also removes the `#blitz` as I assume that's what your code was for. Note how you can leave out the substr() length parameter in such cases.